# Wait(NULL) catch a PID of a child not finished?

Tags: c, parent-child, waitpid

i want that my loop intercept the child process finished or a message sent in the queue by a child. It work if a child sent a message and terminate immediatly...but if i wanna send a message and do other things? I put here my code that work and the variant where i'm working on...

master.c not work: catch pid child despite is not finish for the loop

```
#include "config.h"


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char * args[3] = {CHILD_NAME}; 
    int q_id,num_bytes;
    struct msgUser mt_msg;

    int sh_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,sizeof(int),0644 | IPC_CREAT);
    int *sh_value = shmat(sh_id,NULL,0);
    shmctl(sh_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);

    *sh_value = 0;

#ifndef SO_USERS_NUM
    printf("Error in main:  SO_USERS_NUM not defined");
#endif
    /* 
        Creation users, main do forks as SO_USERS_NUM is setting on confing library.
        A child do a execve to the same file .c with the required operation.
        args: array of string that contains data usefull to user
    */
    q_id = msgget(KEY_QUEUE, IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    for (int i = 0; i < SO_USERS_NUM; i++)
    {
        switch (fork())
        {
        case 0:
#ifdef CHILD_NAME 
            char* test;
            *sh_value = *sh_value +1;
            sprintf(test,"%d",*sh_value);
            args[1] = test;
            args[2] = NULL;          
            execve(CHILD_NAME,args,NULL);
#endif
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;
         case -1:
            printf("Error in main:  forkkodio");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    
    int k_pid = 0;
    while (((k_pid = wait(NULL))>0)){

        printf("\nfiglio: %d",k_pid);   }

    return 0; }
```

master work: wait correctly forever when i put the infinity loop in the user

```
#include "config.h"


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char * args[3] = {CHILD_NAME}; 
    int q_id,num_bytes;
    struct msgUser mt_msg;

    int sh_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,sizeof(int),0644 | IPC_CREAT);
    int *sh_value = shmat(sh_id,NULL,0);
    shmctl(sh_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);

    *sh_value = 0;

#ifndef SO_USERS_NUM
    printf("Error in main:  SO_USERS_NUM not defined");
#endif
    /* 
        Creation users, main do forks as SO_USERS_NUM is setting on confing library.
        A child do a execve to the same file .c with the required operation.
        args: array of string that contains data usefull to user
    */
    q_id = msgget(KEY_QUEUE, IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    for (int i = 0; i < SO_USERS_NUM; i++)
    {
        switch (fork())
        {
        case 0:
#ifdef CHILD_NAME 
            char* test;
            *sh_value = *sh_value +1;
            sprintf(test,"%d",*sh_value);
            args[1] = test;
            args[2] = NULL;          
            execve(CHILD_NAME,args,NULL);
#endif
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;
         case -1:
            printf("Error in main:  forkkodio");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    
    
    while (1) {
         for (int i = 0; i < SO_USERS_NUM; i++)
        {
            printf("\nHo finito di aspettare:%d  sono il padre: %d\n",wait(NULL),getppid());
            /* now receiving the message */
            num_bytes = msgrcv(q_id, &mt_msg, 120, 3, 0);

            if (num_bytes >= 0) {
                /* received a good message (possibly of zero length) */
                printf("\nmessaggio ricevuto: %d \n",mt_msg.numero);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

user.c :

```
#include "user_manager.h"
#include "config.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int q_id;
    struct msgUser my_msg;
    printf("\n user id: %s",argv[1]);
    q_id = msgget(KEY_QUEUE, IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    my_msg.mtype = 3;
    my_msg.numero = 33;
    
    msgsnd(q_id, &my_msg, 120, 0);

    while (1)
    {
        /* code */
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

config.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

struct msgUser {
    long mtype;             /* message type, must be > 0 */
    int numero;
};
/*
    KEY_QUEUE define the start key for the master process.
    Children nodes will increase this value to create owner's queue
*/
#define KEY_QUEUE 0x200800                     
/*
   CHILD_NAME name of users's code lauched by execve
*/
#define CHILD_NAME "user"
/*
   SO_USERS_NUM define the maximum number of users
*/
#define SO_USERS_NUM 3
```

Comment: Catch SIGCHLD and wait in its handler?

Comment: wait(NULL) should return the number of the process child when it finish...but, if i write the master as the first way, it return the pid id despite the while(1) should not allow the child to terminate. I'm not working with signals yet.

Comment: SIGCHLD is automatically sent to the parent when a child ends. It allows the parent to learn when a child exits without having to actively wait for it to exit.

Comment: It would help to see the definition of `msgUser`. Is that in `config.h`? Please _edit_ your question and post this stuff.

Comment: oh ok i understand but..if in the child i put the while(1) it doesn't send to father se signals right??the wait(NULL) should wait forever instead of print the pid of the child and terminate the loop??

Comment: Don't use "magic numbers" (e.g. `120` here): `msgsnd(q_id, &my_msg, 120, 0);` Don't you want: `msgsnd(q_id, &my_msg, sizeof(my_msg), 0);`? Likewise for `msgrcv`

Comment: ok, i'll change the msgsn but it's not the focus of the problem. Thank for the suggestion.

Comment: In the parent, do the `msgrcv` loop. When that completes, do the `wait(NULL)` loop.

Comment: i can wait for all message and after that notify that i child terminate...i cant't do both??

Comment: i can't loop for a message received or process child terminated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do both `wait` and `msgrcv` in the same loop, but you'll have to keep a count of the number of children terminated. And, you'll have to make the calls non-blocking:

```
int pid_done = 0;
while (pid_done < SO_USERS_NUM) {
    num_bytes = sizeof(mt_msg) - sizeof(mt_msg.mtype);

    /* now receiving the message */
    num_bytes = msgrcv(q_id, &mt_msg, num_bytes, 3, IPC_NOWAIT);
    if (num_bytes >= 0) {
        printf("received message");

        /* received a good message (possibly of zero length) */
        if (num_bytes >= sizeof(mt_msg.numero))
            printf(" numero: %d", mt_msg.numero);

        printf("\n");
    }

    pid_t pidnow = waitpid(-1,NULL,WNOHANG);
    if (pidnow > 0) {
        printf("reaped: pid %d\n",pidnow);
        ++pid_done;
    }

    // optional: sleep a bit if no change in state occurred to prevent us from
    // "hammering" the system
    if ((num_bytes < 0) && (pidnow < 0))
        usleep(100);
}
```

Note: As I mentioned in my top comments, using `120` isn't just bad form. But, it is UB (undefined behavior). With it, you'd put data way past the end of the struct. So, the fix is *required*.

---

The above is the simplest way. But, if we establish a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`, we can use blocking calls:

```
int chld_sig = 0;                       // # of children terminated (SIGCHLD)
int chld_reap = 0;                      // # of children reaped (parent loop)

// sigchld -- signal handler for SIGCHLD
void
sigchld(int signo)
{

    // NOTE: we can _not_ do printf inside a signal handler

    // increment number of completed pids
    atomic_fetch_add(&chld_sig,1);
}

void
parent_loop(void)
{

    // using sigaction/sigprocmask, enable signal handler for SIGCHLD ...

    while (chld_reap < SO_USERS_NUM) {
        /* now receiving the message */
        do {
            num_bytes = sizeof(mt_msg) - sizeof(mt_msg.mtype);

            num_bytes = msgrcv(q_id, &mt_msg, num_bytes, 3, 0);

            // probably got EINTR
            if (num_bytes < 0)
                break;

            printf("received message");

            /* received a good message (possibly of zero length) */
            if (num_bytes >= sizeof(mt_msg.numero))
                printf(" numero: %d", mt_msg.numero);

            printf("\n");
        } while (0)

        // check for completed children
        while (1) {
            // get number of signals seen
            int count = atomic_load(&chld_sig);

            // no new child reaped
            if (count <= chld_reap)
                break;

            // reap a child
            pid_t pidnow = waitpid(-1,NULL,0);

            // show the pid of the reaped child
            if (pidnow > 0) {
                printf("reaped: pid %d\n",pidnow);
                ++chld_reap;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> i tried the first implementation and it wait for the child but doesn't print anything like the children doesn't write the message on the queue.

> But, if i start i child it would add a message on the queue and after that, if i start the master it would read the previous message but no new message generated and terminate the child whit their pid printed. –
> Matteo Pagliarello
> 8 hours ago

Because the queue *persists* across executions of master, *if* it *fails* to process all messages on the first invocation, the subsequent invocation will start with "stale" messages.

Thus, it will become further "desynchronized".

You didn't provide the full user code, but I suspect it sent *several* messages.

There was a bug in the loop I provided:

1. It would terminate as soon as it saw SO_USERS_NUM number of children complete.
2. But, there could still be pending messages from various children
3. These pending messages would *remain* after the master terminated
4. They would appear as "stale" in the next invocation.
5. The loop should only terminate when all children have completed **AND** there are no more messages.

Here is the full and complete refactored code. I've combined all files into a single `.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

struct msgUser {
    long mtype;                         /* message type, must be > 0 */
    int xid;                            // process id (sequential)
    pid_t pid;                          // process id (real)
    int numero;
};
#define MSGUSER_SIZE        (sizeof(struct msgUser) - sizeof(long))

/*
    KEY_QUEUE define the start key for the master process.
    Children nodes will increase this value to create owner's queue
*/
#define KEY_QUEUE 0x200800

/*
   CHILD_NAME name of users's code lauched by execve
*/
#define CHILD_NAME "./user"

/*
   SO_USERS_NUM define the maximum number of users
*/
#ifndef SO_USERS_NUM
#define SO_USERS_NUM    3
#endif

// max number of messages
#ifndef MAXMSG
#define MAXMSG          50
#endif

// set this to 1 to force old [broken] behavior in wait_loop
#ifndef FORCE_STALE
#define FORCE_STALE     0
#endif

int q_id;
pid_t pidlist[SO_USERS_NUM];

void
wait_loop(void)
{
    int chld_done = 0;
    int num_bytes;
    struct msgUser mt_msg;

    while (1) {
        num_bytes = MSGUSER_SIZE;

        // NOTE: we can get messages from a given child even after the child
        // has terminated
        num_bytes = msgrcv(q_id, &mt_msg, num_bytes, 3, IPC_NOWAIT);

        /* now receiving the message */
        if (num_bytes >= 0) {
            printf("wait_loop: received message (%d)",num_bytes);

            /* received a good message (possibly of zero length) */
            if (num_bytes >= sizeof(mt_msg.numero)) {
                printf(" xid:%d",mt_msg.xid);
                printf(" numero:%d", mt_msg.numero);
                printf(" pid:%d",mt_msg.pid);
            }

            printf("\n");
        }

        // no pending message
        // stop loop if:
        //   (1) all users reaped
        //   (2) no pending messages (from any child)
        if (chld_done >= SO_USERS_NUM) {
            if (FORCE_STALE || (num_bytes < 0))
                break;
        }

        // has a child just terminated?
        pid_t pidnow = waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);

        // yes, remember the count
        if (pidnow > 0) {
            ++chld_done;

            // get the sequential id number for this pid
            int xid = -1;
            for (int idx = 0;  idx < SO_USERS_NUM;  ++idx) {
                if (pidnow == pidlist[idx]) {
                    xid = idx;
                    break;
                }
            }

            printf("reaped: xid:%d done:%d pid:%d\n", xid, chld_done, pidnow);
        }

        // optional: sleep a bit if no change in state occurred to prevent us
        // from "hammering" the system
        if ((num_bytes < 0) && (pidnow < 0))
            usleep(100);
    }
}

// douser -- do user/child
int
douser(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int q_id;
    struct msgUser my_msg;

    q_id = msgget(KEY_QUEUE, IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    my_msg.mtype = 3;
    my_msg.xid = atoi(argv[1]);
    my_msg.pid = getpid();
    my_msg.numero = 0;

    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);
    srand(ts.tv_nsec);

    int count = (rand() % MAXMSG) + 1;

    printf("user:%d pid:%d (%d messages to send)\n",
        my_msg.xid, my_msg.pid, count);
    fflush(stdout);

    time_t osec = ts.tv_sec;
    while (1) {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);
        if ((ts.tv_sec - osec) >= 1)
            break;
        usleep(1000);
    }

    for (int mno = 0;  mno < count;  ++mno) {
        my_msg.numero = mno;
        msgsnd(q_id, &my_msg, MSGUSER_SIZE, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}

// domaster -- do master/parent
int
domaster(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *args[3] = { CHILD_NAME };

// no need for shared memory -- see below
#if 0
    int sh_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int), 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
    int *sh_value = shmat(sh_id, NULL, 0);
    shmctl(sh_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    *sh_value = 0;
#else
    int sh_value = -1;
#endif

#ifndef SO_USERS_NUM
    printf("Error in main:  SO_USERS_NUM not defined");
#endif

    q_id = msgget(KEY_QUEUE, IPC_CREAT | 0600);

    // drain all "stale" messages
    // NOTE: if we're working correctly, this should never happen
    int drain = 0;
    while (1) {
        struct msgUser mt_msg;
        int num_bytes = MSGUSER_SIZE;

        /* now receiving the message */
        num_bytes = msgrcv(q_id, &mt_msg, num_bytes, 0, IPC_NOWAIT);
        if (num_bytes < 0)
            break;

        ++drain;
    }
    if (drain > 0)
        printf("master: DRAIN %d\n",drain);

    /*
       Creation users, main do forks as SO_USERS_NUM is setting on confing
        library. A child do a execve to the same file .c with the required
        operation. args: array of string that contains data usefull to user */
    for (int i = 0; i < SO_USERS_NUM; i++) {
        // NOTE: by doing this in the parent (before the fork), sh_value does
        // _not_ need to be  in shared memory
        ++sh_value;

        char test[100];

        pid_t pid = fork();
        switch (pid) {
        case 0:
            sprintf(test, "%d", sh_value);
            args[0] = argv[0];
            args[1] = test;
            args[2] = NULL;
            execvp(args[0], args);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;

        case -1:
            printf("Error in main:  forkkodio");
            break;

        default:
            printf("master: launch %d (pid %d)\n",sh_value,pid);
            pidlist[sh_value] = pid;
            break;
        }
    }

    wait_loop();

    return 0;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    setlinebuf(stdout);

    int code;

    if (argc > 1)
        code = douser(argc,argv);
    else
        code = domaster(argc,argv);

    return code;
}
```

Here is the program output:

```
master: launch 0 (pid 3321553)
master: launch 1 (pid 3321554)
master: launch 2 (pid 3321555)
user:0 pid:3321553 (40 messages to send)
user:1 pid:3321554 (44 messages to send)
user:2 pid:3321555 (11 messages to send)
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:0 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:2 numero:0 pid:3321555
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:1 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:2 numero:1 pid:3321555
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:2 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:2 numero:2 pid:3321555
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:3 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:2 numero:3 pid:3321555
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:4 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:2 numero:4 pid:3321555
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:5 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:2 numero:5 pid:3321555
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:6 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:0 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:2 numero:6 pid:3321555
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:7 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:1 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:2 numero:7 pid:3321555
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:8 pid:3321553
reaped: xid:2 done:1 pid:3321555
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:2 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:2 numero:8 pid:3321555
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:9 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:3 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:2 numero:9 pid:3321555
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:10 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:4 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:2 numero:10 pid:3321555
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:11 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:5 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:12 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:6 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:13 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:7 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:14 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:8 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:15 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:9 pid:3321554
reaped: xid:0 done:2 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:16 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:10 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:17 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:11 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:18 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:12 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:19 pid:3321553
reaped: xid:1 done:3 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:13 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:20 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:14 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:21 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:15 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:22 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:16 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:23 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:17 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:24 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:18 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:25 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:19 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:26 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:20 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:27 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:21 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:28 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:22 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:29 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:23 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:30 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:24 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:31 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:25 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:32 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:26 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:33 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:27 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:34 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:28 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:35 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:29 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:36 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:30 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:37 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:31 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:38 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:32 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:0 numero:39 pid:3321553
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:33 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:34 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:35 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:36 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:37 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:38 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:39 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:40 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:41 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:42 pid:3321554
wait_loop: received message (16) xid:1 numero:43 pid:3321554
```

Comment: i tried the first implementation and it wait for the child but doesn't print anything like the children doesn't write the message on the queue. But, if i start i child it would add a message on the queue and after that, if i start the master it would read the previous message but no new message generated and terminate the child whit their pid printed.

Comment: and if i put a while(1) loop in the children is the same.They finish despite the while.

Comment: is like father doesn't launch execve